# TV Schedule or Channel Guide Extension for Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Has anyone seen a TV schedule or channel guide extension for Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't this be done with an events management component, such as Jevents?

Answer (score 0):

I investigated all of the event management and calendar extensions. Nothing comes out of the box with a an hourly layout for a week. I may have to alter Jevents, Jcal or create one from scratch.

Gcalendar uses Google Calendar and looks promising, but I need to test it fully to make sure I have full control over the look and feel of the layout.